# Trying to save a txt file create with BCP on the local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv, bcp

I´m trying to export a text file, with this instructions...

```
DECLARE @selectText VARCHAR(999)
DECLARE @output INT
DECLARE @result INT

EXEC @output = master.dbo.xp_fileexist  'DIR "C:\TextoPlano\" /B', @result OUTPUT

print @output


IF @output = 1
      PRINT 'File Donot exists'--CREATE THE DIRECTORY
ELSE
BEGIN
      PRINT 'File exists'
      SELECT  @selectText = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [pruebaBD].[dbo].[Cliente]" queryout "C:\TextoPlano\ViewOrdenCompra.txt" -c -S xxxxxxx -U sa -P xxxxxx'
      PRINT @selectText
      EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @selectText
END
```

...but sql server shows me this

- SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 and...
- Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-fil

when execute this

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'hostname'

appears my SqlServer name, and all files was saved in c:\ sqlServer

HOW Do I make to save on the local computer that is installed SQL Server???

ex: My Computer C:\TextoPlano

Comment: Since you are running the `bcp` as a dynamic statement after connecting to the server, it would be executed *on* the server. You can try and share  your local drive and map it to the server and then try writing to it.

Comment: did you enabled XP_CMDSHELL with SP_CONFIGURE?

Comment: yes! terrybozzio I did! enable the XP_CMDSHELL

Comment: Verify the path and you have permission to write there.

Comment: Assuming that I undrstand your question correctly: you want to export a file to C: drive that is on your server running SQL Server. Find out what account SQL Server is running under (look in Services), then check if this account has write / create permissions to this directory.

Comment: No! Alex I want to export the file to C: local drive, no at the server running SQL SERVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable XP_CMDSHELL

   -- To allow advanced options to be changed.
   EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
   GO
   -- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   -- To enable the feature.
   EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
   GO
   -- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
2. Verify if the specified path exists
3. Verify do you have permission to write  to write the directory?
4. Verify does SQL Server service account has permission to write the directory?

Thanks